# Unhandled Exception: Binding has not yet been initialized

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

i am facing this error for 3 days, i have just used firebase db for authentication, and i don't know how to solve it
[image]

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 12):

As per their error, answer is contained inside:

[image]

Add this `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();`
before `runApp(const MyApp());`  inside `main()`

Comment: i have added this line instead of that problem has not being solved

Comment: This helped me after I renamed my Flutter package and adding Firebase resulting in only a white screen after building. As I had the same error. Thanks!

Comment: @JeeJeeStudio I was going crazy trying to find the reason my android app wasn't loading past a white screen. your comment clarifying that HardikMaheta's solution solves that helped me alot lol. Thank you

Comment: Awesome! Glad for you that it worked out :)

Answer (score 7):

Try this...

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize the widget rendering  or binding process before the asynchronous call

```
void main() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
        options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );
    runApp(const App());
}
```

Comment: In my case this worked. It was absolutely necessary to have both `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` and 
```lang-js
await Firebase.initializeApp(  
        options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,  
 );
```   
and it _must_ contain the options parameter. I have firebase version 13.2.1 and flutterfire 0.2.7